# Keycloak: REST url for custom endpoint

Tags: java, keycloak

Implementing a custom rest endpoint in keycloak I used these example:

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/domain-extension/src/main/java/org/keycloak/examples/domainextension/rest

After embedding the provider to keycloak it's loaded during keycloak
startup. Guess that's fine. In server info I can see the the endpoint as
well.

Problem:

How may I call that endpoint?

Do I need to registrate the endpoint or mount it on a client?

(If so which settings does the client need (admin rights etc...)

What is the URL for calling the endpoint?

Comment: although you linked your example sources it is not quite a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i think you would attract many more people if you were to post an actual, full example - preferrably one which is downloadable with only a few clicks / one click and is able to run on any standard IDE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your don't need register or mount your endpoint.
the effective url is calculated with the given id in your ProviderFactory.

```
{{keycloakUrl}}/auth/realms/{{reamlName}}/{{id in providerFactory}}/...
```

For your example the url is

```
{{keycloakUrl}}/auth/realms/{{realmName}}/example/companies
```